# multiple inputs in python

Tags: python

I am trying to input multiple entries but when I run these statements, it does not as expected. Suppose I want to read name and age of person.

```
num1=raw_input("ENter a number :");
nam1=raw_input("What is your name:");
print num1;
ENter a number :nam1=raw_input("What is your name:")
print nam1;

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "input", line 1, in module

NameError: name 'nam1' is not defined
```

So, If I execute these two statements in console, it reads the second statement as the input to first queries, i.e. takes nam=raw_input("Whats your name:") as the nam1.

Is there way to enter one input at a time while executing multiple statements simultaneously?

Thanks !

Comment: How is this question related to JavaScript and R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use ; to terminate lines using python.

```
num1=raw_input("ENter a number :"); #<= remove the ; here
nam1=raw_input("What is your name:"); #<= remove the ; here
```

clean version :

```
num1 = raw_input("ENter a number :")
nam1 = raw_input("What is your name:")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you, you must be copying multiple lines in to shell, which isn't what you are supposed to do.

If you want to copy the code into shell, you need to make it a single line:
`num1=raw_input("ENter a number :");nam1=raw_input("What is your name:");print num1;print nam1`

Notice that this is a single line.
As you can see, I'm using semicolons here in order to specify where each statement ends.
If you would like to run it in multiple lines, you need to put your code into a `.py` file and run it with python.
Running a file would work with ot without the semicolons, but since you are doing multiple lines, there would be no need for semicolons, so discard them:

```
num1 = raw_input("ENter a number :")
nam1 = raw_input("What is your name:")
print num1
print nam1
```